# JavaScript function to check if only has digits or decimals in string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check to see if my string only have numbers or decimals in it using JavaScript.

If it has only numbers or decimals in the string then it should pass else it want to display a alert saying there is a error.

I have tried using the following code but it doesn't alert anything..

Am I doing something wrong?

```
var myString = "abc"; 

        if (myString.matches("[0-9].") && myString.length() > 2) 
        {
            alert("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Error");
        }
```

Comment: length is not a function... so that's why nothing was happening. mystring.length > 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify :-)

```
 if (/^[\d\.]{3,}$/.test(myString)) {
    alert("Pass");
 } else {
    alert("Error");
 }
```

Comment: Lol just noticed that I put `d{2,}` too, and changed it as well.

Comment: If I make myString = "12.3" it displays Error where decimals should be allowed as well as 0-9

Comment: Note: there may be a problems, cause text **1..2** will match too.
Use something more complex like: `\d+(\.\d+)?` and then make check your string length

Answer (score 1):

use `^\d*[0-9](\.\d*[0-9])?$`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/LhthW/2/)**

```
if (myString.match(/^\d*[0-9](\.\d*[0-9])?$/) && myString.length > 2) {
        alert("Pass");
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/^\d+$/.test(myString)
```

Returns a boolean instead of an array or null, which is what `match` does. Altogether:

```
if (/^\d{2,}$/.test(myString)){ 
...
}else{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it all together like this:

```
alert( /^\d{3,}$/.test( myString ) ? 'Pass' : 'Error' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong myString.length() is a function not actually a length of myString

```
var myString = "abc"; 

    if (myString.match(/[0-9]/, "g") && myString.length > 2) 
    {
        alert("Pass");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error");
    }
```